Matrices display in preview but not after posting
If you look at my answer to 
How to quickly estimate a lower bound on correlation for a large number of stocks?
you will see that I tried posting a 3x3 matrix using \begin{matrix}...\end{matrix}.  It showed up fine in the preview, but scrunched into a single line after I posted it.  As a quick hack I edited the post to insert some semicolons,

Thanks @Brian.  Great contributions.  Just nominated you for moderator: http://meta.quant.stackexchange.com/questions/41/who-should-the-moderators-be/90#90
